# python - parse email - special characters

Tags: python, email, special-characters, decode, encode

I could use some help reading email with special characters in it and outputting that email with the characters.

So far I have witnessed email come in with the character sets: "UTF-8", "windows-1252", "ISO-8859-1"

I have seen

```
‘hey’
```

represented as

```
=91hey=92
```

and

```
‘’,“”=hey÷½Öñ♦→%@¥÷
```

represented as

```
=E2=80=98=E2=80=99,=E2=80=9C=E2=80=9D=3Dhey=C3=B7=C2=BD=C3=96=C3=B1=E2=99=A6=E2=86=92%@=C2=A5=C3=B7
```

(I removed two `=` signs above because of line breaks)

sometimes these seem to be hex representations because I can put them into `binascii.unhexlify()` and get the proper result back.

there were a few others where if I dropped the `=` and put `\x` and ran it through `"myString".decode('iso-8859-1')` I got the right thing.

I'm pretty confused, how do I decode the email text?

Comment: You need to read the email headers to see how it's encoded. Your example looks like quoted-printable, and would be decoded with the `quopri` module in the standard library.

Comment: this works for my second example which I believe to be Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable [link](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/module-quopri.html) and [link](http://effbot.org/librarybook/quopri.htm) helped. 

The first example I believe is Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable 

which seems to need different treatment

Comment: this seems to do it (pastebin)[link](http://pastebin.com/D9hn68p5) Thanks a bunch! If this wasn't a comment I'd mark it as right as it seems to solve my issues for now. But it wouldn't be the first time I thought I was on the right track. thank you very much. this has helped a lot.